# Combine two rpm into one

Tags: rpm, rhel

I have coded two RHEL applications. Both applications communicate with each other when one is run. Due to legacy issue I can't combine them into one. Currently I am making two packages (one for each application) and installing them differently in system through script. I want to merge those two packages into one, so that when user install that one integrated package both application get installed i.e, for user only one package is installed but in background two packages get installed.
Please tell me is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a third package that `Requires` the other two and install that with `yum`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.    I need to combine two different pacakges into one package so that I give only only one package to user instead of two different pacages

Comment: The correct thing to do here is to publish a repository. Or combine the two into a single RPM if you must have a single RPM.